# Trying to customize this Regular Expression to Extract Medical Report Result

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to correct this regular expression 
`Lung[ ]+Rads[ ]+Catagory[ ]+(\\d+[A-Z]*)`
 to extract the 1, 1S, 2, 2S, 3, 3S, 4A, 4AS, 4B, 4BS, 4X, 4XS and the potential add on of C to those multiples as well, from the Lung Rads Catagory in unstructured radiology reports, where the language may look like :

```
LUNG RADS CATEGORY 2
Lung RADS category 1, 
Lung RADS category 2. 
LUNG RADS CATEGORY 1
Lung RADS 3S.
Lung RADS Category 1:
Lung RADS Category 1 (S):
LUNG RADS CATEGORY 1 S
Lung RADS category: 2S.
Lung RADS: 2C
Lung RADS category 4B,
Lung RADS category 1S.
Lung RADS: 3.
Lung RADS category I
Lung RADS 2
LUNG RADS CATEGORY:I
LUNGRADS 2
LUNGRAD 2
LUNG-RAD 3
```

Comment: Try `/Lung(?:\s*|-)Rads?(?:\s+Category)?:?\s*((?:\d+[A-Z]*|[A-Z]+)(?: *\(?[A-Z]+\)?)?)/i`, see https://regex101.com/r/E4FfdX/1

Comment: You want `1S` and `2S` - do you want `1 (S)`? Is the period or comma, as your sample shows, inconsistent? Do you want all of `LUNG RADS` & `LUNGRADS` & `LUNGRAD` & `LUNG-RAD` with a match to count? (Your `Lung[ ]+Rads[ ]+...` would *not* match the lines without a space such as "LUNGRAD" or "LUNG-RAD") — you need to be _really_ specific about what counts as a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following regular expression to match the part of the string of interest.

```
(?<=^(?:(?:Lung|LUNG) RADS:?(?: CATEGORY:?| [cC]ategory:?)? ?|LUNGRADS? |LUNG-RAD ))(?:\d[A-Z]?|[A-Z])(?![A-Z])
```

[Javascript demo](https://regex101.com/r/FXzD7V/1/)

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=                      begin positive lookbehind
  ^                       match beginning of line
  (?:                     begin a non-cap grp
    (?:Lung|LUNG) RADS:?  match 'Lung' or 'LUNG' followed by a a space,
                          then 'RADS', opt followed by ':
    (?:                   begin non-cap grp
      [ ]CATEGORY:?       match space, then 'CATEGORY', then opt ':"
      |                   or
      [ ][cC]ategory:?    match space then 'category' or 'Category'
                          then opt ':'
    )                     end non-cap grp
    ?                     opt match non-cap grp
    [ ]?                  opt match a space
    |                     or
    LUNGRADS?[ ]          match 'LUNGRAD ' or 'LUNGRADS '
    |                     or
    LUNG-RAD[ ]           match 'LUNG-RAD '       
  )                       end non-cap grp
)                         end positive lookbehind
(?:                       begin non-cap grp
  \d[A-Z]?                match digit then opt cap letter
  |                       or
  [A-Z]                   match one cap letter
)                         end non-cap grp
(?![A-Z])                 match a cap letter in a negative lookahead
```